# Meteor Query Filtering with Search Source

Tags: javascript, meteor, atmosphere.js

I have successfully implemented The basic search source setup as outlined in the setup on the Github README for [Arunoda's Meteor Package](https://github.com/meteorhacks/search-source). I am now attempting to add filters to work with the search. These filter options are found on a separate search page and consist of checkboxes that can be checked on or off. I have come up with the following server method I call with the event handler.

```
 searchFilter: function (option) {

var selectorCity = {
  city: 'Queens'
};

var selectorCategory = {
  category: 'Apparel'
};

console.log(selectorCategory);

  var query = Listing.find({ $and:[ selectorCategory, selectorCity ] }).fetch();
  console.log(query);
  return query;
```

}

The query executes successfully and finds and logs (in the console) the single document I am testing with. It however does not change the output on the page to that query. I believe I may have to use SearchSource's getData() method but I am not sure how.

What options are available for rendering the content on to the page?

Comment: Don't see any question as posted. Can you clarify what the question is?

Comment: My question is "How can I refine searches with the Meteor Search Source?". I know how to specify entire collections to search by and now I want to know how to refine the search to match only specific options of the collections I am searching by. On the search page there is a category checkbox for shoes. When the user checks this box they should only see items of the shoe category as opposed to all the categories. I am stuck at making that category search refinement work properly.

Comment: Does look like you are not in an helper. Your function shall be like that: Template.<template name>.helpers({searchFilter : function(option) {...}});. You say that your template is not reactive, i'm right ?